# How to apply the styles like h1, h2 in CKEditor using the Copy Formatting option

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

How to apply the headings 1-6 and alignment is same as that source in CKEditor plugin using Copy Formatting option?

I would configure my js like this

```
config.copyformatting_disallowRules ="";
```

but it won't work at all.

I will call the `config.copyformatting.disallowRules` it will always shows this:

```
*[data-cke-widget*,data-widget*,data-cke-realelement](cke_widget*)
```

Comment: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading/issues/72 this link will be helpful.

Comment: ok dude thank you i will refer

Comment: still i don't have any idea to solve the problem.please help me

Comment: Please do share your code to get it verified with the goal defined